# Pandas equivalent to SQL where

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas and I am having some trouble.  Basically I'm trying to implement the SQL query

```
select count(fraud),state
from table
where fraud='REJECT'
group by state
```

I have the following python code

```
df.groupby('State').size()
```

however, this does not restrict to only fraud=='REJECT'.  I tried

```
fraud=df['fraud']=='REJECT'
fraud.groupby('State').size()
```

however this creates a key error for 'State'.  So I think it boils down to I don't know how to implement an SQL 'where' in Pandas.  Can someone help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
df[df['fraud'] == 'REJECT'].groupby('State').size()
```

example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'fraud':['REJECT', 'ACCEPT', 'REJECT', 'REJECT'], 'State':['AZ', 'AZ', 'TX', 'TX']})
>>> df[df['fraud'] == 'REJECT'].groupby('State').size()
State
AZ       1
TX       2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: when I print this it only gives Series([], dtype: int64)

Comment: my fault! It was actually ' REJECT' instead of 'REJECT'. Thats why it was empty.  Thanks!